# Libreoffice readonly document with one specified name

Tags: linux, libreoffice, debian-squeeze

I can't edit file with one *name* on my computer.
When I try to save new file with name `/home/lissin/Рабочий стол/Без имени 1.odt` I got error `can't save file`. When I rename any other document to that *name* and try to open I got popup `can't edit file, create new form it or open readonly`. If I open it readonly I can edit it after pressing [edit](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/578/cant-edit-my-word-doc-why/) button, but after that can't save it with same error. 
Right after pressing button I got warning that file is readonly.
When I go to  File>Properties>Security before pressing edit button both checkboxes are gray, after pressing - both are unchecked.
Permissions to that file are `-rw-r--r--`, it owned by current user and no selinux/apparmor installed, any other application can create/modify/delete file with such name.

Files with other name, for example `/home/lissin/Рабочий стол/Без имени 2.odt` are opened and edited without any issue.

I'm using libreoffice 4.1.0 on debian 7.2

What should I do to allow libreoffice modify file with that name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check if there is a lock file for the file you are trying to save. Enable showing hidden files in your file browser or do a *ls -la* in a terminal window and look for a file like ".~lock.Без имени 1.odt#". If one is present, make sure you close all LibreOffice windows and delete it with your file browser or *rm*.

These files can get left behind if LibreOffice isn't closed properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, there are really some lock files with that name, after removing them I can open and edit file.

Comment: Sure thing. I've run into this problem myself several times. Please mark your post as answered so other people know. :)

Comment: There is some timeout when question can't be marked as answered :)

Comment: Cool cool, haven't used this site to much until today. I realized there were a lot of questions I could answer so I'd thought I'd help out some. :)